# WooCommerce Rest Api: Get the orders by specific date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I want to get the orders by specific date using WooCommerce Rest Api. The Api provides orders method which accept only ID. But I want to get the specific order at specific date.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For this you'll need to look at the WooCommerce **orders** endpoint. Specifically around the **after** and **before** filters.

Eg.

GET wp-json/wc/v3/orders?after=2016-06-22T00:00:00&before=2016-06-22T23:59:59per_page=100

Comment: Incredible! "T00:00:00" this code save me a lot of wste time! Great

Comment: @Andrew A. Barber how to create a endpoint URL for such scenarios?

Comment: Thank you, this helps! Although I would have wanted to select a different date for comparison, not `date_created`.